# How to get the selected value from the dropdown

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get the value selected from the dropdown using the below snippet of code:

```
Select dropdown  = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("items"))));

WebElement tmp = dropdown.getFirstSelectedOption();
tmp.getText();  
String s = tmp.getText();  
System.out.println(s);
```

When I run the application it gives me following error:

> org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element not found
>   in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up

Thank You

Comment: What code do you have before it?

Comment: Are you adding an element or making any changes coz the DOM which selenium loaded has changed somehow.You can reload the page just before this operation.

Comment: Hi  alecxe, Following is the code in my method                             public void addDessingationNoData() throws Exception {
driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("AddDesignation"))).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("viewAll"))).click();
 Thread.sleep(5000);

Comment: And the remaining code:                                          Select dropdown  = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("items"))));
dropdown.selectByValue(prop.getProperty("firstValue")); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("apply"))).click();    WebElement tmp = dropdown.getFirstSelectedOption();    tmp.getText();    String s=tmp.getText();

Answer (score 0):

boolean flag = false;
 Select dropdown  = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("items"))));

```
       List<WebElement> list = dropdown.getOptions();
        for (WebElement temp : list) { 
if (temp.getText().equals(prop.getProperty("your value").toString())) {
flag = true;
```

}

}

Comment: You can print out the value.

Comment: Thanks Vishal for your time. The requirement is like there is a dropdown. If we select any value in the dropdown(say 5) and submit it will display a table below with the number of rows selected in the dropdown(in this case 5). I have 5,10,20,40,60 values in the drop down and need to compare the no of rows with the value in dropdown. I am able to get the no of rows in table but couldn't get the dropdown value selected.

Comment: In the code posted by you, it is iterating through the list of options and comparing the value that we pass with getProperty(). If any one of the values in the list is matching it will return true. But need only the selected value in dropdown. Thanks once again